# Criar um array dos links e nomes de custom post type para utilizar em uma meta_box sem alterar o valor do post em edição

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou trabalhando no desenvolvimento de um plugin para WordPress utilizando dois tipos de post. O primeiro tipo é criado e atualizado normalmente, e estou tentando usá-lo para criar um `dropdown` no segundo tipo. Contudo, quando chamo a função que gera o array para o post que estou trabalhando, todos os dados das demais metaboxes são perdidos.

Código da função que retorna o array:

```
function array_integrantes($custom) {

    global $post;
    $old_post = get_post_custom($custom->ID);
    $type = 'clero';
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

            $integrantes[] = array(
                'nome_integrante' => get_the_title(), 
                'link_integrante' => get_permalink()
            );

        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_reset_query();

    $post = get_post_custom($old_post->ID);
    return $integrantes;
}
```

Código onde chamo a função:

```
function paroquia_info($post) {
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $paroco = $custom["paroco"][0];
    $vigarios = $custom["vigarios"][0];
    $endereco = $custom["endereco"][0];
    $cep = $custom["cep"][0];
    $cidade = $custom["cidade"][0];
    $telefone = $custom["telefone"][0];
    $email = $custom["email"][0];
    $site = $custom["site"][0];
    $facebook = $custom["facebook"][0];
    $integrantes = array_integrantes($custom);
    echo'treco bugado<br><br><br>';   

    foreach ($integrantes as $row) {
        echo $row['nome_integrante'].'<br>';
        echo $row['link_integrante'].'<br>';   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Você percebeu que o seu método `paroquia_info()` não foi fechado, certo? E `$integrantes[] = array (` deveria ser `$integrantes = array(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não dá pra testar seu código, pois não é um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), mas acho que a probabilidade é muito grande que o problema seja no `WP_Query`.
E também:

- o `global $post;` vai acessar o post atual (se for na edição de um post/page), não entendo porquê está usando;
- as duas chamadas para a função `get_post_custom()` parece que não servem para nada.

Basicamente é: não use a função `WP_Query` em plugins rodando no *backend*, a função [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) não tem [perigo nenhum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) de influir em outras queries que estão acontecendo, ela simplesmente faz a consulta e devolve uma array com os resultados. Não tem métodos nem funções auxiliares como `have_posts`, `the_post` ou `the_title`, a gente só tem que fazer uma iteração no objeto que ela devolve e extrair a informação com `get_the_title($ID)`, `get_the_permalink($ID`, etc.

Os argumentos são exatamente os mesmos que em `WP_Query`. Atenção para `$post->ID`, `$post->post_title`, etc:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type'       => 'clero',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
$integrantes = array();
foreach ( $posts as $post ) 
{
    $integrantes[] = array(
        'nome_integrante' => $post->post_title, 
        'link_integrante' => get_permalink( $post->ID )
    );
}
// "var_dump" formatado com <pre> 
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $integrantes, true ) );
```